# How to use DoctineModule ObjectSelect based on custom repository method?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a table with a list of person that belong to different categories A and B for example. My problem is that i have a form with DoctrineModule ObjectSelect and  i want to show in the ObjectSelect only the name of persons of Category A.

I find this https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md#example-3--extended-version but the example is not clear for me and i don't know how to adapt it to my case.

Thank you.

excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite similar to the example you were looking at (I guess that's why there is no example for it), the only difference is that instead of using find/findBy/... you pass your custom repository name as name key, with code similar to this:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'my-select-object',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'attributes' => array(
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'My Label',
            'object_manager'  => $entityManager,
            'target_class'    => 'Application\Entity\MyEntity',
            'property'       => 'name',
            'is_method'      => true,
            'find_method'    => array(
                'name'   => 'myCustomRepositoryMethod',
                'params' => array(
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ));
```

Also notice that your entity needs to know about repository existence, so make sure it uses this line:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repository\MyCustomRepository")
```

So when you open the form with this ObjectSelect it will call you repository method instead of loading the dropdown directly. That method should just return an array of entity objects which are then used by ObjectSelect to generate select element's options.